# Springboot 3 hibernate repository save problem

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, repository

I have been trying for the entire day to migrate from springboot 2.7.9 to springboot 3.0.5
I have encountered a problem with the new hibernate:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.persister.collection.CollectionPersister.getRole()" because "this.loadedPersister" is null
```

when calling repository.save(entity)

The repository extends JpaRepository. The entity contains oneToMany, manyToOne fields.
Weirdly it happens only in some cases (but consistently) - f.e. I have 2 update methods, when I call one which updates part of data it's always okay, when I call second one which updates more parts of data, it always fails (details are maybe useless).

The only thing from config that I changed is that I added

```
spring:
  jpa:
    init:
      platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.PostgreSQLPlatform
```

Other changes to take into account are maybe upgrading ehcache version and also upgrading hibernate-types-52 to:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-types-60</artifactId>
   <version>${hibernate-types.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

(I used this for fulltext search https://dev.to/fabiothiroki/setup-spring-and-postgres-for-full-text-search-4n97 -  I had to rewrite SqlFunctionContributor to use PatternBasedSqmFunctionDescriptor instead of SQLFunctionTemplate)

Answer (score 6):

This is an issue present in Hibernate 6.1.7. It has been fixed in 6.2.0: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16169. Unfortunately, there are currently no versions of the Spring Data starter that use the fixed version.

You can reconfigure logging to not log debug messages from the Hibernate classes to work around it until a fixed version of Spring Data is available.

Spring Data 3.0.x doesn't appear to work with Hibernate 6.2.x either, unfortunately.

Comment: What do you suggest as a solution? use an earlier version of Spring?

Comment: @Steven disable debug level logging for Hibernate classes. Info level is ok. This was enough to avoid triggering the issue, at least for me.

Comment: Spring boot data starter from version 3.1.0 fixes this issue by working with Hibernate 6.2.x